# Image not rounded properly

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I want to display round image. I have a square image and I round it using below code.

```
    public static void roundImageForImageView(ImageView imageView) {

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            int diameter = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

            final int color = 0xff424242;
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            int rectX = (bitmap.getWidth() - diameter) / 2;
            int rectY = (bitmap.getHeight() - diameter) / 2;

            final Rect rect = new Rect(rectX, rectY, rectX + diameter, rectY
                    + diameter);

            final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
            final float roundPx = diameter;

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(output);

            bitmap = null;
            output = null;
        } catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

ImageView layout :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:background = "@drawable/placeholder"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description" />
```

But displayed image has small tiny cuts on middle of all edges. I tried playing with image size.

[image]

Any idea of why these cuts are there or how to solve it?

**Update : ** Using `android:scaleType="center"` for `ImageView` gives below result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake in layout file.

```
android:background = "@drawable/placeholder"
```

Above line was causing the blurry edged circle to appear. `@drawable/placeholder` is an image and that itself is blurry.

I had set it as `background`, instead of `src`.

```
android:src = "@drawable/placeholder"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

This is cropping the image and making the lines at the top bottom left and right.

try using

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Also, take a look [here at ImageView.ScaleTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for some good info on the different scale types: